# Incomplete group enumeration - AD using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a tried and true function that determines if an AD user is a member of a specific group. Been using it for years without a problem. Until now. I am developing a new app using C# .net, and created a new AD group to control access. My account is a member of the group in question, so should pass this validation, but it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
public bool isGroupMember(strUserID)
{
    bool b = false;
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com", strADUserID, strADPassword);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(root);
    search.Filter = "samAccountName=" + strUserID;
    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    short groups = result.Properties("memberOf").Count() - 1;
    string Group = null;
    short i = 0;
    while (!(b == true | i == groups)) {
        Group = result.Properties("memberOf")(i).ToString;
        if (Group == "CN=MyGroup,OU=GroupOU,DC=domain,DC=com") {
            b = true;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return b;
}
```

The problem is that that while my account is a member of 22 groups, the line

```
short groups = result.Properties("memberOf").Count() - 1;
```

returns only 20 groups not 22, and the group I am after (being new) is either group 21 or 22 so the loop has already exited before it gets to the group. Why is the group enumeration not complete? Why 20 groups when it ought to be 22?

Comment: your syntax looks off shouldn't it be like this 
`result.Properties["memberOf"][i].ToString();` is that `VB or C#` you're coding in..??

Comment: Part of your problem is that you're subtracting 1 from the count.  You don't need to do that, and it will always cause the last group to be skipped.

Comment: Roger, I am subtracting 1 because it is a zero based index. THat is intentional. If there are 21 groups, that would be group 0 through group 20.

Comment: DJ Kraze, right you are. But the issue remains.

Comment: Roger, Removing the -1 does the trick, add that as an answer rather than a comment and I will credit you. DOn't know why the count would produce count-1, but if that's how it works, that's how it works! :-)